# Is $I:=\{ f \in A : \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0 \}$ a prime ideal ? How does maximal ideals containing $I$ look like?

Tags: analysis, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be the ring of all real valued continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ under pointwise addition and multiplication  , I have seen that $I:=\{ f \in A : \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0 \}$ is a proper ideal of $A$ ; is $I$ a prime ideal of $A$ ? Let $M$ be a maximal ideal containing $I$ , does $\exists c \in \mathbb R : f(c)=0 , \forall f \in M  $ ?

Comment: as things are currently written, $I$ is not an ideal... see comment on my answer. I think you need to add the hypothesis that the functions in $A$ are bounded.

Comment: @hunter : I think it was given $f(x)=0 $ for $|x|$ sufficiently large , then I have to place $|x| \to \infty$ instead of $x \to \infty$ .... does it work ?

Comment: Is f(x)=0 for |x| sufficiently large how you meant to define I?Then you seem to be OK that I is an ideal, but it's still not prime (see hunter's answer below).

Comment: If $f(x)$ is zero for $|x|$ sufficiently large then your ideal is the whole ring. Check the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that you have non converging to zero functions whose product is equal to $0$ ? Example : $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{Q}}$ and $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{R}\backslash\mathbf{Q}}$ if you don't require continuity : their product is in $I$, but they are not in $I$. Other example for continuity : take $f$ to be the function equal to $0$ for negative $x$ and $x$ for positive $x$, and $g$ the function $x\mapsto f(-x)$... there product is zero, but they are not in $I$.

Answer (score 1):

First, $I$ is not prime. Take two continuous functions, neither of which tend to zero (for example, because they oscillate) but which have disjoint support; then their product is zero and in particular is in $I$, but neither are in $I$.

Such a $c$ clearly does not exist, as the elements of $I$ themselves do not have this property.

Comment: do you mean to say that there is an element $f \in I$ not having this property ? Indeed I think $f(x):=\dfrac 1{x^2+1}$ works ; but I am not getting an example to violate primality of $I$ , please elaborate

Comment: You gave the same answer that I did, 3 minutes after I did, but deleted your comment under my answer, showing that you have seen my update of it. By the way, you don't even prove what you assert, whereas I do.

Comment: @user10000100_u I deleted my comment because you fixed your answer. I posted my answer (which I was in the middle of when you posted yours) becuase you didn't answer the second part of the question.

Comment: @hunter too bad... lol. But you don't show that your example works... lol

Comment: @SaunDev something is wrong ... $I$ is not an ideal. For example, $1/(1+x^2)$ is in $I$ but when you multiply by $1+x^2$ you get $1$, which is not in $I$. Are you sure you recorded all the hypotheses of the problem ?